# prove $S(n) \leq (5/2)^n$

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

I've been flipping through my math book for nearly 5 hours working on these recursive problems and it's just not clicking.

I have a recusrive sequence

$S(0) =1$

$S(1)=2$

$S(n) = 2S(n-1) +S(n-2)$ for $n \geq 2$

I need to prove $S(n)$ $\leq$ $(5/2)^n$ for $n \geq 0$

I get to this step:  $2S(n) + S(n-1) \leq ((5/2)^2) (5/2)$  but at this step I"m not sure what to do. I know I need to use my induction hypothesis but I don't see how.

Answer (score 3):

$1 \le (5/2)^0$ and $2 \le (5/2)^1$. Now apply the induction step. If $s_{n-2} \le (5/2)^{n-2}$ and $s_{n-1} \le (5/2)^{n-1}$ then $$s_n \le 2 \left( \frac 52 \right)^{n-1} + \left(\frac 52 \right)^{n-2} = \left(\frac 52 \right)^{n-2} (5 + 1) < \left(\frac 52 \right)^{n-2}  \frac{25}{4} = \left(\frac 52 \right)^n.$$

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you have S(n-2) <= (5/2)^(n-2) is this your hypothesis? 

I thought that when you were proving by induction you proved the base case. Then added 1 to N not subtracted?

Comment: Let $P(n)$ be a statement about the nonnegative integer $n$. If $P(0)$ is true, $P(1)$ is true, and $P(n)$ is true whenever $P(n-1)$ and $P(n-2)$ are true, then $P(n)$ is true for all $n$.

Comment: So on this step sn≤2(52)n−1+(52)n−2

You're subbing in (5/2) into this part 2S(n−1)+S(n−2) for S(n-1) and S(n-2)?

Answer (score 0):

To Prove:
$$S(n) \le (5/2)^n$$

By definition:
$$2S(n - 1) + S(n-2) \le (5/2)^n$$

Rewrite, need to prove:
$$S(n-1) \le \frac{(5/2)^n - S(n-2)}{2}$$

To prove $a \le b$, if you can assume $a \le c$, then it suffices to prove $c \le b$.  By induction we can assume $S(n-1) \le (5/2)^{n-1}$.  So:

$$(5/2)^{n-1} \le \frac{(5/2)^n - S(n-2)}{2}$$

Rewrite:

$$2(5/2)^{n-1} + S(n-2) \le (5/2)^{n}$$

Similarly for $S(n-2)$ :

$$2(5/2)^{n-1} + (5/2)^{n-2} \le (5/2)^{n}$$

Multiply through by $(5/2)^{-n}$:

$$2(5/2)^{-1} + (5/2)^{-2} \le 1$$

Multiply through by $5^2$:

$$2\cdot 5 \cdot 2 + 2^2 \le 5^2$$
$$24 < 25$$
$$\top$$